# Angular 5 upload multiple images through formdat

Tags: angular, spring-boot

As I am using angular5 as front-end and backend with spring boot...
When iam uploading files through the form data..and the formData is getting empty..

Here is the sample code

```js
  onFileChanged(event: any) {
    this.files = event.target.files;
    console.log(this.files)
  }
  
  onUpload() {
    const formData = new FormData;
    for (let file of this.files) {
      console.log('gdsgsfsd')
        formData.append('hihi', file.name);
    }
    console.log('gdsgsfsd',formData)
  }
```

```html
<input id="file-input" type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" multiple >
```

Answer (score 0):

Add file object as the second parameter in append method.

```
onUpload() {
    const formData = new FormData;
    for (let file of this.files) {
        console.log('gdsgsfsd')
        formData.append('hihi', file, file.name);
    }
    console.log('gdsgsfsd', formData);
}
```

Comment: Thank You...Really saved some time

Comment: Yup...But I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer...as am new to StackOverflow